# Can we include multiple JS libraries in nintex form?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I know there is one option 'Custom JavaScript Includes' in the setting of Nintex form. We can include reference for any other library like KnockOut JS or Angular JS in 'Custom JavaScript Includes' option.

I want to develop nintex form on SharePoint Server 2013. So my question is that can we include only single JS library or can we include multiple JS libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Guess we can, just copy the libraries in the site asset or a document library in the same site and copy the url of the library and paste it under form setting -> Custom JavaScript.

Note : add a line break after every URL